# Get payload from all notifications using NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to act upon the content of a notification send by Android another app (not mine). With `NotificationListenerService` I can easily see all incoming notifications from all apps, including their title, text, subText, ... but not their payload.

Is there are a way to get their payload too? Because that contains the essential information (most likely an URL or an ID to item in the app) I need.